# Cannot access git hub secrets inside git hub actions bash script

Tags: bash, github, github-actions, cicd, github-secret

I am trying to run a bash script file in git hub actions and inside the bash script I want to access values stored in git hub secrets. The git hub actions step I have for this is

```
steps:
- name: test-step
  env:
     test_value: ${{ secrets.TEST_VALUE }}
     test_value_2: SOME_VALUE
  run: |
     bash ./test.sh
```

The contents of test.sh are

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "test_value"
echo $test_value
echo "test_value"
echo $test_value_2
```

But when I check the outputs for this job, I only see an empty value for `$test_value` which should print the contents of `secrets.TEST_VALUE`.

```
test_value

test_value_2
SOME_VALUE
```

I also made sure the `TEST_VALUE` exists in the git hub secrets. I'm not sure what I'm missing here

Comment: The output would be redacted like `***` in any case. You should see the environment values in the logs of the action, is `test_value` set there?

Comment: Also, try quoting: `echo "$test_value"`

Comment: In case you're using an environment and defined secrets under it, you need to verify if it's configured correctly in your workflow.